# unable to share auto text on facebook in ios 8 .

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8, xcode6, facebook-ios-sdk

When I click on fb icon to share auto text, it appear in popup view if am not logged in. but if I login in facebook application it doesn't appear the auto text.However it works proper on twitter and mail.

Answer (score 0):

This is intended behaviour. Pre-filling is [not allowed (2.3)](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#control) and when using the Facebook App, this is programatically enforced.